# How do I stop git push from quietly failing to publish local commits

Tags: git, github

I am working on a fork of a github repo, successfully pushed twice, but now git push quietly fails to publish my local commits:

```
$ git version
git version 1.8.3.1

$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:martinwaite/vault.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:martinwaite/vault.git (push)

$ git status
# On branch batch_hmac
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/batch_hmac' by 2 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

$ git push
$ git push origin batch_hmac
$ git push origin HEAD
$ git status
# On branch batch_hmac
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/batch_hmac' by 2 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

Please, any ideas on what is going wrong here and how I can fix it ?

Comment: what does `git fetch` give you?

Comment: `git fetch` quietly returns in the same way as `git push`

Comment: Note that `git@github.com:<path>` is equivalent to `ssh://git@github.com/<path>`. If that exits silently, it suggests that your ssh installation is messed-up somehow.

Comment: @torek - it certainly looks that way.  I don't understand how it pushed OK a couple of times, and how it reports the commit status correctly, but then fails to push.  I'll investigate further.

Comment: `git status` never tries to contact the remote at all. Only push, fetch, and `git ls-remote` *have* to do that; `git remote show` will sometimes do that as well, depending on flags. Running any of these with the env variable `GIT_TRACE` set to 1 will show the ssh command being run. There are more tracing variables available as well; see the main `git` documentation and search for GIT_TRACE.

Comment: For ssh issues, it's often useful to run ssh yourself: `ssh -vvvT git@github.com` and look at all the resulting messages.

Comment: @torek - thanks for the debugging tips.  I now think that the cause of the problem in this case is their .git/hooks/pre-push script.  When I remove that, all works fine.

Comment: Aha, yes, a pre-push script is allowed to abort a push. The script itself should announce that it's doing so, and why, but perhaps Git should make a note about it just in case, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to reset the url of the remote using https:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/martinwaite/vault.git
```

Then fetch the remote repo:

```
git fetch
```

Double check that the local branch is tracking the remote one

```
git branch -vv
```

If that is not the case make the local branch track the remote one

```
git branch -u origin/batch_hmac
```

Finally push the commits

```
git push
```

If still does not work try a `--force` push

```
git push --force
```

Comment: @b_fg - please check that I fixed up the typos correctly

Comment: @b_fg - apologies for the delay.